# Is it possible to "mix in: additional type constraints

Tags: scala

I'd like to add constraints to a type field in a trait as additional traits are mixed in but can't seem to find a way to express it.  Any help appreciated:

```
trait Events { def be() = println("B") }
trait Create { self : Events => def create() = println("C") }
trait Update { self : Events => def update() = println("U") }
trait Delete { self : Events => def delete() = println("D") }

trait EventHandler {
  type MyEvents <: Events
  val myEvents : MyEvents
}

trait Creation {
  self: EventHandler =>
  override type MyEvents <: Create
}

def h(events: EventHandler with Creation) : Unit = {
  events.myEvents.be()  // <== wont' compile
  events.myEvents.create()
}
```

Compiler says:

```
<console>:12: error: value be is not a member of events.MyEvents
```

Comment: See my revised answer below, this was a learning item for me as well - I'd try to migrate away from so many self-types

Answer (score 0):

Ok some of my previous comments were in error, I didn't realize self typing hides the interface you're working with and thus is not the same as "extends". Here's a link that explains it better:

http://www.andrewrollins.com/2014/08/07/scala-cake-pattern-self-type-annotations-vs-inheritance/

There's too many logical conflicts this creates in your code, and so I won't attempt to rework it here. Those conflicts in your code come down to this - some of your logic is opening up the trait API, and some of your self-types are then immediately hiding them. Here's an example that helped me understand why

```
trait A {
   def x:Int
 }
  trait B { self:A =>

  }

  def workWithB(b:B): Unit ={
    b.x  //wont' compile, is forced hidden.
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea but doesn't quite work -- override apparently completely overrides the definition so myEvents is no longer "Events with Create" but simply "Create"  (in the scope of Creation presumably) 

What's missing is some way to express "<what it was before i got mixed in> with Create".  in other words something like "super.MyEvents with Create"

Comment: @user3324500 perhaps I'm not understanding, because Create is defined as " self : Events => " , it is already (by definition) an "Events with Create". There would be no reason to do declare that syntax again.

Comment: Interesting, I'd always thought of "self: Events =>" as different from "Create extends Events" -- the latter is a fact that "Create is a sub-type of Events" while the former does not impact the type of Create at all but rather constrains the types of instances it can be a part of.  PS I also tried "override type MyEvents = self.type.MyEvents with Create" with the same result

Comment: @user3324500 trust me the example I supplied will always work, the use of the self type is perfectly locked in the same way as the phrase "extends". The only meaningful difference is that trait can't be instantiated on its own - but it must always obey the self-type

Comment: I'm moving your completed example up as my problem statement and highlighting where the compiler still has a beef...